# Dozer mapping collection

Tags: dozer

I am new to using dozer. I need to map a collection to a class that is an attribute for the source class in the collect.
I have a class technology as follows

```
Class Technology { 
       String name
       List<TechnologyOwner> techOwners
}
```

that I  would like to map to

```
Class TechSummary {
   String name
   List<Employee> techOwners
}
```

where

```
class TechOwner {
   Employee techOwner;
   Date sinceDt;
}
```

How will my dozer mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the resolve scheme:
1. add mapping configuration in dozerBeanMapping.xml:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>demo.Technology</class-a>
    <class-b>demo.TechSummary</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>techOwners</a>
        <b>techOwners</b>
        <b-hint>java.lang.String</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

2.use dozer mapper to create destination class:

```
Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance();
TechSummary techSummary = mapper.map(t,TechSummary.class);
```

It will be worked.